# Where can I find a Prizm Polarized filter?

Tags: filters, polarizer

Recently I have purchased Prizm sun glasses, and the moment I used them outdoors I was shocked with the result. Words cannot describe the beauty of colors and differences between Polarized and Prizm.

Question: where to find it?

Comment: On your second question: please ask separate questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

"Prizm" is a trademark of Oakley, the high-priced sunglasses company. It's not a generic term, nor is it a technical improvement on a polarizing filter.

From what I understand in reading between the lines of the marketing material, these glasses simply are color filters which reduce some frequencies in a way that increases the perception of contrast in bright sunlight outdoors. Since this is sold as a fancy specialized secret, they don't tell you exactly *what* the transmission curve looks like. Some of their marketing materials indicate that this is likey to be different for different Prizm models, even.

Oakley doesn't sell camera filters, and I don't think anyone has reverse-engineered the sunglasses and adapted them to cameras — although you are not the first to have the idea... here's a [forum post from two years ago](http://www.newschoolers.com/forum/thread/813514/Oakley-Prizm-Technology-in-Camera-Filters) wondering about it.

You basically have two options. First, you could certainly take apart a pair of sunglasses and make a DIY option. Since the sunglasses don't use flat glass, you'd need to invent your own holder. Or, you can replicate the effect in post-processing; unlike polarization, this reduction of certain colors can be easily done in post. In fact, popular preset-effects app VSCO has actually licensed the Oakley Prizm name [for a set of presets](https://petapixel.com/2017/07/13/vscoxoakley-photo-filters-let-see-life-sunglasses/), although I'm not sure if this is still available as it's described as [for a limited time](http://vsco.co/vsco/journal/oakley-x-vsco). In any case, it wouldn't be particularly hard to replicate the effect. Personally, from the examples, I suspect that this is something that's nice in real life but less interesting when "cooked" into a photo.

Comment: I used to just hang my [polarised] Revos over the lens of my iPhone for that 'warm  glow & reduced reflections' look. Worked fine on a phone... never tried it on a camera.

Answer (score 0):

As product recommendations are not allowed, please don't confuse this with one.  In fact I've never used these, so keep that in mind.

There are some combination color adjusting and polarizing filters available from Singh-Ray.  Here's the link : http://www.singh-ray.com/color-enhancing-polarizers/

I can't say if these are any better than using e.g. two filters (one polarizer and one color enhancement), although I've seen the Blue-Yellow polarizer discussed as a very specialized and striking filter (but not suitable for everything !).